# Prevent default select input behaviour by using link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select box based on bootstrap and jQuery which uses the following plugin:http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/

It is an icon picker. The select box behaves like an input field and shows a dropdown with icons.

What I'm trying to do is prevent the select box for being shown and instead, use a link to open the dropdown (display the select options).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#icon_upload_link").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myselect:hidden").trigger('focus');
  });
});
```

```css
#myselect {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="icon_upload_link">Select Icon </a>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect" class="myselect">
  <option value="">No icon</option>
  <option>icon-headphones</option>
  <option>icon-music</option>
  <option>icon-play</option>
  <option>icon-video-camera</option>
  <option>icon-dice</option>
</select>
```

I can't seem to get it to work. If I use it without the link, it works fine. Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: am not sure of what you are trying to achieve but try this $("#myselect").show();

Comment: use show(), not focus

Comment: do you want to open the select's options on link click?

Comment: @vijayP Indeed. I'm trying to show the dropdown, rather than the select box. The dropdown is not the conventional dropdown, but a custom one style in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at below code. Here I am trying to open the icon picker programatically:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#myselect').fontIconPicker();

  $("#icon_upload_link").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myselect').prev(".icons-selector").find("span.selector-button").trigger('click');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.js?v=2.0.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/css/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.css?v=2.0.0" />



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/themes/grey-theme/jquery.fonticonpicker.grey.min.css" />

<!-- optional themes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/themes/dark-grey-theme/jquery.fonticonpicker.darkgrey.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/themes/bootstrap-theme/jquery.fonticonpicker.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/themes/inverted-theme/jquery.fonticonpicker.inverted.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/fontello-7275ca86/css/fontello.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/icomoon/style.css" />


<a href="" id="icon_upload_link">Select Icon </a>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect" class="myselect">
  <option value="">No icon</option>
  <option>icon-headphones</option>
  <option>icon-music</option>
  <option>icon-play</option>
  <option>icon-video-camera</option>
  <option>icon-dice</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.show()`in jquery. it for show the select box with id myselect visible in front end

```
$("#myselect").show();
```

your code be like

```
$(function(){
        $("#icon_upload_link").on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#myselect").show();
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try css in that, from display none to block.

```
$(function(){
    $("#icon_upload_link").on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#myselect").css('display','block');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should refactor selects to another bootstrap dropdowns. As I know the select can be open by JS only in chrome using this code:

```
event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
document.getElementById('myselect').dispatchEvent(event);
```

there are many options how to avoid using selects